# VS2013 won't debug a specific web application

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a web application that uses IIS, but when I try to debug it VS just locks up and gives me the hour glass cursor icon. No browser window opens, nor does an instance pop up in the Task Manager. VS says its Running / not "Not Responding", but I cannot interact with the IDE. Can't Ctrl-Break to stop or anything.

I was able to run it before, and I'm not aware of any system or IIS changes that could cause this. I've disabled source control and I've tried launching the app in both Chrome and IE but it still behaves the exact same way as described above.

Has anyone else encountered this? The only threads I could find just describe general slowness in the IDE but otherwise its functional. The recommended fix was to disable the source control functionality, which as I said I already tried.

I should note that I don't seem to have an issue running & debugging winforms applications. I also just created a web application and was able to launch it in Chrome and get to the homepage. Also, it doesn't make a difference if I have a breakpoint set or not.

This solution has 4 different projects. If I set a *different* project as the Startup Project, it does run and launches the browser but it just gives me a 'file explorer' sort of view where it just lists the files in that project's directly which is obviously not what I want.

Edit; If I manually open a browser tab, try to navigate to `http://localhost/myApplication`, VS pops up and asks if I want to attach process `w3wp.exe` to `IIS APPPOOL\myAppPool`. If I attach, it opens a new tab in Chrome and my application runs. But unless I do these 2 steps, it does not run.

Comment: Visual studio may be corrupted. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: @Krythic Updated my post with a tid bit more info about other things I can run, so I don't think that's the case but I'll ask the sys admins to repair my installation as I cannot do it myself :/

Comment: @Krythic Unfortunately repairing the install didn't fix the issue

Comment: Corrupted project then? Can you have someone else try to open it?